# How to use preg_match to match numbers between hyphens?

Tags: php, preg-match

I need to validate strings like this:

```
$string = 'test3-10-2';
```

I need the penultimate number between hyphens, so in this case '10'. These are other examples:

```
$string2 = 'test45-50-178-1';  //match = 178
$string3 = 'test45-580-89-12-1';  //match = 12
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this RegExp should do the trick using a positive lookahead: (change 4 to whatever max num of digits you want to allow)

```
\d{1,4}(?=-\d{1,4}$)
```

Comment: Thx ! it works. If I would to match the last two numbers between hyphens ? Eg. $string3 = 'test45-580-89-12-10';  //match = 12 and 1

Comment: In that case all you have to do is remove the positive lookahead to include it in the match, like so: `\d{1,4}-\d{1,4}$`

Comment: ok, but In these way I obtain : $matches = 12-10 . I need $matches = array(12,10); It's possible ?  (Note i made a typo in the next comment. I wrote //match = 12 and 1  but I intend //match = 12 and 10)

Comment: you can explode the result like @Kelly suggested and you'll get an array, or use capturing groups by sorrounding the nums in the regexp with brackets: `(\d{1,4})-(\d{1,4})$`. then you refer to the groups by $1 and $2

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the `explode` function (which is like a `split`):

```
$items = explode("-",$yourString);
end($items);
$whatYouWant = prev($items);
```